# I have a question regarding the subordinate conjunction

Tags: syntax

If the conjunction "that" is removed from the noun clause, Is it still a complex sentence? Because some people said that subordinate conjunction "that" is optional.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about the grammar of English specifically, not about linguistics (i.e. the scientific study of language). As such it likely belongs on either the English or ELL sites instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about linguistics

Comment: You can ask this question on ELL, the learners site. In fact, I think it has already been answered there.

Comment: The connector word *that* can be explicit or understood, and the sentence is still complex for having two clauses. As a trivial parallel, a friend asks if you want vanilla or chocolate. You answer vanilla, and your friend says you get no ice cream for saying vanilla, not "I'd like vanilla ice cream, please." But it was understood.

Comment: Oh, I commented on your question based on your previous post on English Stack Exchange. But you should post the sentence again here. Like "I know (that) he is honest" is the traditional complex sentence with or without **that**. The clause "He is honest" depends on the clause "I know."